# Can't display list of my targets with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I add targets to the database this way:

```
private fun addTarget(name: String, description: String) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        val target = Target(guid = "some", name = name, description = description)
        databaseReference?.child("users")
            ?.child(mUserId.toString())?.child("targets")?.push()?.setValue(target)
    } else Log.d("some", "Enter a name")
}
```

And get the following structure in my firebase database:

[image]

Next, I try to display my list of targets in `TargetsFragment`
In `onViewCreated` i call next functions:

```
private fun updateListData() {
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        getTargetsFromDb()
    }
private fun getTargetsFromDb() {
        databaseReference?.child("users")?.child(mUserId.toString())?.
            child("targets")?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (targetSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val target = targetSnapshot.getValue(Target::class.java)
                    target?.let { targetList.add(it) }
                }
                recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in your database forbidden characters. Are you sure you don't get that error when you add data?

Comment: @AlexMamo i resolved problem with this error, but also can't display my targets

Comment: @Morozov what you mean can't display my target. Can you log the `targetList` to check if data is added.

Comment: @Ashish data is empty( but in firebase console i can added this targets, now try to solve the problem with communication fragments

Comment: @Ashish  don't really understand why I have `targetList` empty

Comment: If you use `Log.d(TAG, target.name)` what is printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo I think he receives the data what he is looking for But he didn't provided list to adapter and yet he didn't try to log it.

Comment: @AlexMamo in `onDataChange` ? 
nothing

Comment: Is in `onDataChange()`. Have you tried to put a breakpint? Is `onDataChange()` even called?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't know how to work with breakpoint correct( but when i log,   I'm not getting any

Comment: @AlexMamo i see in logs what i called method: `onDataChange`. And write next log:
`Log.d("some", "data: ${dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue()}")` and get `data: null`

Comment: @Morozov just log the `dataSnapshot.children` and check if you're getting any children in there.

Comment: @Ashish `children: com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot$1@df52b82`

Comment: @Morozov You should call `Log.d("some", "data: ${dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String::class.java)}")`. Does it work that way?

Comment: @AlexMamo get `null`

Comment: And you don't get any error, right? Because I cannot see what you are actually doing, I'll write answer with some code.

Comment: @AlexMamo wait a minute, i will show some gist. I hope it will be useful

Comment: @AlexMamo https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/ecf9556e31e5966fa42c8b2b085b37e8

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: @AlexMamo answer is awesome, mb u can check also this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562650/display-target-data-from-firebase

Comment: @Morozov Just answered your new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, because I cannot see what changes do you make, I wrote the code that can help you get the data from the database:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val targetsRef = rootRef!!.child("targets").child("users").child(uid).child("targets")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val target = ds.getValue(Target::class.java)
            targetList.add(target)
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
targetsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
uuuuu
yyyyy
```

Even if you are using two nodes with the same name `targets`, both should be mentioned in the reference.

Comment: super!, now I get in the logs my targets
Now i need only to display them in the recyclerView

Comment: In that case, simply get the `DataSnapshot` object and convert it to an object of type `Target` (as you do in your code). Add those objects to a list and your problem will be solved. Please confirm to me when it works.